# Simplifying where clause when a column is mutual for the tables at from clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to learn if there is any more efficient way to write the query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   requests srp 
       INNER JOIN surgeons rpsur 
               ON rpsur.id = srp.surgeon_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #usersurgeons usersurgeons 
                    ON usersurgeons.surgeon_id = srp.surgeon_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN surgeons LOsurgeons 
                    ON usersurgeons.surgeon_id = LOsurgeons.id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN provsurgeons LOprovsurgeons 
                    ON LOprovsurgeons.id = LOsurgeons.provsurgeon_id 
       INNER JOIN #selectedsurgeons up 
               ON up.surgeon_id = rpsur.id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN provsurgeons ps 
                    ON ps.id = rpsur.provsurgeon_id 
WHERE  rpsur.isprimary = 0 
       AND usersurgeons.isprimary = 0 
       AND LOsurgeons.isprimary = 0 
       AND LOprovsurgeons.isprimary = 0 
       AND up.isprimary = 0 
       AND ps.isprimary = 0
```

I am not happy with the where clause here, is there any more professional way to write this, rather than adding the clauses to the join lines (such as `on xx.id = yy.id and xx.isPrimary=0`)??

Comment: Note that this query will give you different results if you move the "where" clause expressions to their join lines.  If you have a "left outer join" but then filter it like this in the "where" clause, then you have made it into an "inner join" instead.

Comment: Why *are* those left outer joins when your where clause just turns them back into inner joins anyway? What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this query alone there are not many things that can be said. You should consider adding some more context (how do you get data into those temporary tables and the structure of %surgeons tables):

1) `Select *` makes almost impossible to use any index and also provides a lot of columns (`Requests.*`, `surgeons.*`, `Provsurgeons.*` etc.) in your final result. Return only the columns that you need.

2) If `isPrimary = 0` filtering is performed often in your queries (not just this one), you can consider creating a view that fetches data filtered by isPrimary = 0. E.g. `vwSurgeons`, `vwProvsurgeons`. Then, you can just JOIN directly to the view instead of the table.

3) [already mentioned in the comments] Any condition that excludes `NULL` values for the `OUTER JOIN`ed table will transform the `OUTER` into `INNER`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining all tables and having a where clause at the end, use a derived tables only with filtered records. This way your query performance will be better. 

`SELECT * 
FROM   requests srp 
INNER JOIN surgeons rpsur 
               ON rpsur.id = srp.surgeon_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       (
       SELECT * 
       FROM #usersurgeons
       WHERE isprimary = 0 
       )usersurgeons 
       ON usersurgeons.surgeon_id = srp.surgeon_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
       SELECT * 
       FROM surgeons
       WHERE  isprimary = 0 
       )LOsurgeons 
        ON usersurgeons.surgeon_id = LOsurgeons.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       (
        SELECT * 
       FROM provsurgeons
       WHERE isprimary = 0
       )LOprovsurgeons 
       ON LOprovsurgeons.id = LOsurgeons.provsurgeon_id 
INNER JOIN 
       (
       SELECT *
       FROM #selectedsurgeons 
       WHERE  isprimary = 0 
       )up 
        ON up.surgeon_id = rpsur.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       (
       SELECT *
       FROM provsurgeons
       WHERE isprimary = 0
       ) ps 
        ON ps.id = rpsur.provsurgeon_id 
        WHERE  rpsur.isprimary = 0`